# JSF backing bean and hibernate entity same class?

Tags: hibernate, jsf

Can I use the same class for a JSF backing bean and a hibernate entity?  I assumed that I could but when I do some JSF validation on the backing bean, the fields are not set (i.e. null).

Is there something I'm missing to make these two technologies play nicely together?  Or is it simply not the practice to use the same class for both?

Thanks for any help.

Joe

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure technically but it doesn't make much sense logically.  You're hibernate beans are associated to database records while your JSF backing beans are associated to user sessions.  I think trying mix the two in the same class will cause nothing but confusion.

Comment: Ok.  Appreciate the comment.  I'll try separating them and look at the architecture.  Might make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know you can use one class for both purposes but I'm not sure and the reason for that is because I personally never use it that way as it's bad coding practice. First as JOTN mentioned Entity classes reflect your DB and backing beans are associated with the view. Second of all, and for me it's the most important reason, the fields in the entity class and the backing bean don't have to be the same! What if you want a password and a "reenter password" fields in the backing bean and only one in the entity class?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases use the same class. Frameworks like richfaces even provide support for ajax validation based on `javax.validation` annotations on the class.

In most cases this would be a safe and easier to maintain approach.

In rarer cases you can create a special object for the view, but that's not so common.

Although the separation seems like a good idea, in practice you usually end up with many pairs of identical classes - a sign of overdesign.

If your session and transaction management is well-defined, then you should not have any problems.

Comment: Right.  Exactly!  This is why I wanted to comnbined them.  But, considering the troubles that I'm running into, I think I'll separate them.

Comment: I know this is an old post but I am having problems as well combining managed bean and hibernate on the same class. Should I create a new SO question for this?

Comment: probably would be best, yes

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's better to ask a framework to do the integration job for you. Use JBoss Seam and it does what you want and even more.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it an anti-pattern to use DTO (Data Transfer Object) in the first place? Hibernate has been trumpeting the removal of any separation of domain model objects in presentation layer and persistence layer. Only with Hibernate proxied objects in the servlet engine can you guarantee dirty checking. Otherwise, one will have to maintain plumbing codes to update the persistent objects with DTOs.

I haven't been developing JSF in the past, but now I'm looking to do so and I'm asking the same question. I have a feeling it's probably better off using the JPA objects in combination with faces-config.xml rather than using @ManagedBean annotation in combination with JPA annotations.

Answer (score 0):

This thread is getting old but the topic is still hot.  Working on a large web application with JSF and hibernate, I would side with Bozho and say that it is better to use only 1 set of classes if you can.

While the session and transaction management services can be a little tricky to set up; you will end up with an architecture that:

- Performs better. Mapping between DTOs and Entities can be resource expansive, especially if you use a 3rd party library that relies on reflection like dozer. Also hibernate has a very efficient caching system that you loose if you systematically map the parents/children of your entities
- Is more Maintainable.  1 set of classes is easier to manage than 2, plus with hibernate annotations you can easily tell which fields are hibernate managed and which are not
- Scales better. (Performance + Maintenability)